# Give a connected graph whose automorphism group has size 3

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

Find a connected graph whose automorphism group has size 3.

Note: I know such graph must be non-simple.

Comment: An oriented triangle?

Comment: If you're allowed directed graphs, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every group is isomorphic to the automorphism group of a simple graph (see [Frucht's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem)), including the cyclic group of order $3$.

To construct a simple graph $G$ whose automorphism group has size $3$, take $K_3$ and, for each edge, replace it by a copy of a graph $G$ with no non-trivial automorphisms ($F$ say, which could be the [Frucht graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph)).  [This operation needs to be performed in the same way for each edge.]

Any automorphism of $G$ must map a copy of $F$ to another copy of $F$, which, since $F$ has no non-trivial automorphisms, can be achieved in precisely $3$ ways.  (Any other automorphisms would give rise to a non-trivial automorphism of $F$.)

Here's a drawing:

[image: A simple graph with automorphism group of size 3]

(thanks to Mathematica)

Comment: What does "replace an edge by a copy of F" mean? Does this operation give a resultant graph with 3 mutually adjacent F-graphs such that each two share a common vertex?

Comment: I think it has 6 automorphisms instead of 3?!

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: There are some exceptions, if the graph G is a tree you must be very careful of which vertices you use to be the end points of the new "edge" and for some trees it will be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favorite, it shows that you do not need an asymmetric graph as the edge.   [image: Using a graph with symmetries as the "edge"],