# Build graph with exactly n automorphisms

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Construct graph with exactly distinct n automorphisms. For n $\geq$ 2.
I wonder if we can just take an asymmetric graph, such as this one as building block.
[image: 6-vertex asymmetric graph]

Comment: It suffices to do this for $n$ odd, as the cyclic graph on $n$ nodes has $2n$ automorphisms.

Comment: It equally suffices to do this for $n$ a prime power, as an automorphism on a union of two disjoint nonisomorphic graphs is the combination of an automorphism on each part.

Comment: It may interest you to know that the minimal graph with 3 automorphisms has 9 vertices and 15 edges.

Comment: Relevant: http://oeis.org/A080803

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140288/give-a-connected-graph-whose-automorphism-group-has-size-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This graph has exactly five automorphisms:

[image: Graph with exactly five automorphisms]

And it's easy to see how to construct a similar graph with $n$ automorphisms for any $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Do you mean 5 automorphism by rotating 72 degrees around the center? It seems correct. I tried to flip the image around the vertices, but it results in different graph.

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

[Frucht's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem) says that every finite group can be realized as the group of automorphisms of a graph, and the Wikipedia essay gives some idea of the proof, and some links.

Of course, for every $n$ there is a group of order $n$.